# Can I use the default class for a generic?

Tags: c#, generics

I have a class defined as:

```
public class FindResultEx <TL> where TL : TagLocation
{
}
```

Three questions on this. First is there a way to create an instance of this class where I go `new FindResultEx()` and it's the same as `new FindResultEx()<TagLocation>`?

Second, is there a way to have a returned value declared as being of type `FindResultEx` and it then assumes it's `FindResultEx<TagLocation>`?

Third, if I do define or cast something to `FindResultEx<TagLocation>`, that will handle objects of type `FindResultEx<ExtendedFromTagLocation>` - correct?

Comment: 1) No. 2) No. 3) Use a covariant interface.

Comment: @SLaks - thank you

Comment: Actually, the answer to nr 1 and 2 can be yes-ish, if you also declare: `public class FindResult : FindResult<TagLocation> { }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just want to point out that your first and second question is kind of possible if you just overload the class with a default.

```
public class FindResultEx <TL> where TL : TagLocation
{
}

public class FindResultEx: FindResultEx<TagLocation>
{
}
```

The third question is possible using an interface with [Covariance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance)

Answer (score 2):

First and second questions - no. `FindResultEx` and `FindResultEx<T>` are two completely different classes.
Third question - actually no. But you can use interface with covariant parameter like this `IFindResultEx<out T>`. You may read more about Covariance from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance).

Comment: Classes cannot be co-variant, only interfaces and delegates can be defined with co-variant generic types.

Comment: @juharr you are right. Thank you. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

`FindResultEx` and `FindResultEx<T>` are 2 completely different types.

However, you can create a class `FindResultEx` that inherits from `FindResultEx()<TagLocation>`.

This creates an inheritance relationship such that any `FindResultEx` IS a `FindResultEx<TagLocation>` but an object of type `FindResultEx<TagLocation>` IS NOT a `FindResultEx`.